# How can I delete a message without mailbox file lock? I'm using Perl's Mail::Box

Tags: perl, cpan, postfix-mta, email-bounces

I run **Postfix** on Ubuntu 16.04 server to send "internal email" messages and a crontab Perl job to parse the related bounce messages (delivered to local mailbox */var/mail/bounceparser*). The Perl code basically checks the *bounceparser* mailbox, parse all the messages and take some actions (delete bounced addresses, etc).

The problem is that when I try to delete those already-parsed messages using **Mail::Box** library, the mailbox gets locked and if a new message arrives the postfix daemon throws an exception trying to deliver the message: "cannot update mailbox /var/mail/bounceparser for user bounceparser. cannot open file: Permission denied".

Is there a way to delete a message without locking the mailbox file? If it's not possible, any other suggested strategy?

The code I use to delete the messages:

```
my $mbox = Mail::Box::Mbox->new(folder =>'/var/mail/bounceparser', access => 'rw');

# @mailbox_pending_deletes contains the list of message ids to delete
for my $message_id (@mailbox_pending_deletes){
   $message = $mbox->find($message_id);
   $message->delete;    
}    
my $delete_result = $mbox->close(write=>'MODIFIED');
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure, but if your directory is locked, you can try to modify it creating a new [Mail::Box::Locker](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mail-Box/lib/Mail/Box/Locker.pod) and passing it  when you create your Mail::Box::Mbox object.

Comment: Thanks for the idea ^_^,  I'm now checking how Postfix delivery *mailbox_delivery_lock* parameter works.- maybe they are using different default locking methods? I'll update.

Comment: This is my first Perl code ^_^ but I'm just having the lock issue randomly for now, and most of the times the related code works properly.- For parsing the messages I'm using [Sisimai](http://libsisimai.org/en/), not the Mail::Box parse functions...

Comment: If the  mail box is in mbox format (i.e. all mails within one file) it needs to be locked if you modify it because otherwise it gets corrupt when two processes modify the file (i.e. delete from it and append at the same time). You need to use maildir or similar formats where each mail is a separate file.

Comment: Ok, I see that Postfix use *mailbox_delivery_lock = fcntl, dotlock* default values for mail delivery locks, and Mail::Box use DotLock as the default value for locking. I don't know what means to have 2 methods for Postfix (it checks both?), but I'm going to change config to just use dotlock. I will update if that solves the issue...

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I would like to get default Postfix delivery agent, may I expect that my previous message will solve the issue?

Comment: @NachoColl: the previous comment does not solve the issue, i.e. either you will still get a lock conflict or you might end up with a corrupt mailbox.The default delivery agent in postfix supports multiple mailbox formats, including maildir. To cite from [local](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html): *Specify  a  name
       ending in / for qmail-compatible maildir delivery.*

Comment: Ok, if I set both to use dotlock locking Postfix then gets blocked when trying to deliver the message: "cannot update mailbox /var/mail/bounceparser for user bounceparser. unable to create lock file /var/mail/bounceparser.lock: File exists".- So basically it's bad to use single file model.- As @SteffenUllrich suggested I must go for another mailbox model ^_^ .- Let's check if Sisimai and Mail::Box work properly then ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @SteffenUllrich using mailbox single file box it's not a good idea (sincerely I was using it just because it's the default Postfix configured value ^_^).

So, if you have a similar issue 1.- Configure Postfix to use **Maildir** instead of Mailbox for messages delivery (main.cf file):

```
# Set Postfix to deliver messages to Maildir user folder
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

and 2.- use **Mail::Box:Maildir** and not the Mail::Box:Mbox I was using to find-delete the messages.

```
my $mbox = Mail::Box::Maildir->new(folder =>'/home/bounceparser/Maildir', access => 'rw');

# @mailbox_pending_deletes contains the list of message ids to delete
for my $message_id (@mailbox_pending_deletes){
   $message = $mbox->find($message_id);
   $message->delete;    
}    
my $delete_result = $mbox->close(write=>'MODIFIED');
```

Fortunately the Sisimai library I use to parse the bounce/delivery/etc messages also accepts a Maildir path to go for the messages:

```
my $v = Sisimai->make('/home/bounceparser/Maildir/new','hook'=>$x);
```

Thanks for helping!